# Why can Rust floating point values hold large values with few significant figures, whereas integers cannot?

Tags: rust, floating-point

Why is it that only floating point values in Rust appear to be able to hold large values with few significant figures, whereas integers cannot?

```
println!("{}", std::f64::MAX); // 1.7976931348623157e199
println!("{}", std::i64::MAX); // 9223372036854775807
```

If I have an integer, i.e. `99e100` is there any primitive in Rust that can store that value as an integer, or am I forced to use a float?

Comment: What precision do you need for your big integers? Do you only need a few significant places, or so you want to store _all_ digits of the integer? If all you need is the former, a floating point type is exactly what you want to use. In the latter case, you will need some arbitrary precision integer implementation, as explained in Benjamin Lindley's answer.

Comment: Even as an `f64` the number `99e100` cannot be represented exactly. It's exact value is actually `999999999999999967336168804116691273849533185806555472917961779471295845921727862608739868455469056`.

Answer (score 4):

Rust primitives are a fixed size. As such, there are a finite number of unique values they can store, to be no greater than 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the type. In the case of the integer types, those bit patterns are assigned to every successive integer up to the number of values they can represent, starting from 0. Furthermore, in the case of signed integers, half of those patterns are assigned to negative numbers.

Given these specifications, the maximum value that an `i64` can hold is 2^63-1 (which is the number you printed). The largest signed integer type `i128`, can hold a value up to 2^127-1. And if you use `u128` you can get all the way up to 2^128-1. That is the largest value that a primitive integer type can hold in Rust, significantly less than your request for 99e100.

If you want larger integers, you need to use either a larger fixed size type, or an unbounded type, which grows as needed. Neither of these are part of the Rust standard. So you will have to either write your own implementation, or use someone else's, such as [the num crate](https://github.com/rust-num/num).